# How to specify HTTP authentication (user, password) when using an URL for libvirt_volume.source

Tags: centos, terraform, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

I am trying to Provision VMs with Terraform.
i give the source image for the vm
here:
source = "http://10.1.1.160/Builds/14.7.1.10_0.39637/output/KVM/14.7.1.10_0.39637-disk1.qcow2"

but this site require a user name and a password.
where and how can i specify the credentials of this site in my tf file?

this is my main.tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    libvirt = {
      source = "dmacvicar/libvirt"
    }
  }
}

provider "libvirt" {
    uri = "qemu:///system"
}

resource "libvirt_volume" "centos7-qcow2" {
  name = "centos7.qcow2"
  pool = "default"
  source = "http://10.1.1.160/Builds/14.7.1.10_0.39637/output/KVM/14.7.1.10_0.39637-disk1.qcow2"
  format = "qcow2"
}

# Define KVM domain to create
resource "libvirt_domain" "gw" {
  name   = "gw"
  memory = "8192"
  vcpu   = 4

  network_interface {
    network_name = "default"
  }

  disk {
    volume_id = "${libvirt_volume.centos7-qcow2.id}"
  }

  console {
    type = "pty"
    target_type = "serial"
    target_port = "0"
  }

  graphics {
    type = "spice"
    listen_type = "address"
    autoport = true
  }
}
```

when i run *terraform apply* i got this error:

```
*Error while determining image type for http://10.1.1.160/Builds/14.7.1.10_0.39637/output/KVM/14.7.1.10_0.39637-disk1.qcow2: Can't retrieve partial header of resource to determine file type: http://10.1.1.160/Builds/14.7.1.10_0.39637/output/KVM/14.7.1.10_0.39637-disk1.qcow2 - 401 Authorization Required

   with libvirt_volume.centos7-qcow2,
   on main.tf line 13, in resource "libvirt_volume" "centos7-qcow2":
   13: resource "libvirt_volume" "centos7-qcow2" {*
```

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the password and the user to the URL, like this:

*http://user:password@host/path*

:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).